# Cakephp Version 2.x Unable to Show selected file name in edit view

Tags: php, cakephp, file-io, editview

Hopefully this is a simple issue.

I have a Cakephp MVC set to upload an image and store it in a database table.
Index, View and Add are working as I want.

However, in the Edit view how can I indicate that the record currently has an uploaded image that I may with to keep of change .

I have not been able to figure out what to set in the attributes of the File Input Button to show the existing file name.

```
<div class="imageEdit form">
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('VwImage', array('action' => 'edit', 'type' => 'file') );
    echo $this->Form->input('image_category', array(
        'options' => $partCat,
        'selected' => $this->data['VwImage']['image_category'],
         'type'=>'select', 'empty' => '(Choose One)'));
    echo $this->Form->input('description');         
    echo $this->Form->input('image', array( 'value' => $this->data['VwImage']['file_name'],
                        'type' => 'file'));

    echo $this->Form->submit('Save');
    echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

Controller Code for edit

```
    public function edit( $id = null) {

    $this->loadModel('VwPartsCategory');
    $partCat= $this->VwPartsCategory->find('list',
                array( 'order' => 'short_name ASC' )); // Get parts categories from the database
    $this->set('partCat', $partCat);

    if(!$id && empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid Id for Image');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    } 

    if (!empty($this->request->data) &&
        is_uploaded_file($this->request->data['VwImage']['image']['tmp_name'])) {

        $fileData = fread(fopen($this->request->data['VwImage']['image']['tmp_name'], "r"),
                $this->request->data['VwImage']['image']['size']);

        /** get image information **/
        $size = getimagesize($this->request->data['VwImage']['image']['tmp_name']);
        $image_width = $size[0];
        $image_height = $size[1];
        $image_size = $size[3];
        $image_type = $size['mime'];
        $image_thumb = null;

        /** Create a second variable for the thumbnail **/
        $thumb_data = $this->request->data['VwImage']['image']['tmp_name'];
        $aspect_ratio = (float) ($image_width / $image_height );
        $thumb_height = 100;
        $thumb_width = $thumb_height * $aspect_ratio;
        if($image_type == 'image/jpeg' ) {
            $src = ImageCreateFromjpeg($thumb_data);
            $destImage = ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
            ImageCopyResampled($destImage, $src, 0,0,0,0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $image_width, $image_height);
            ob_start();
            imageJPEG($destImage);
            $image_thumb = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
        }
        if($image_type == 'image/gif' ) {
            $src = ImageCreateFromgif($thumb_data);
            $destImage = ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
            ImageCopyResampled($destImage, $src, 0,0,0,0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $image_width, $image_height);
            ob_start();
            imageJPEG($destImage);
            $image_thumb = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
        }
        if($image_type == 'image/png' ) {
            $src = ImageCreateFrompng($thumb_data);
            $destImage = ImageCreateTrueColor($thumb_width, $thumb_height);
            ImageCopyResampled($destImage, $src, 0,0,0,0, $thumb_width, $thumb_height, $image_width, $image_height);
            ob_start();
            imageJPEG($destImage);
            $image_thumb = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
        }


        $this->request->data['VwImage']['file_name'] = $this->request->data['VwImage']['image']['name'];
        $this->request->data['VwImage']['file_type'] = $this->request->data['VwImage']['image']['type'];
        $this->request->data['VwImage']['size'] = $this->request->data['VwImage']['image']['size'];                 
        $this->request->data['VwImage']['image'] = $fileData;
        $this->request->data['VwImage']['id'] = $id;

        if(!$image_thumb == null) {
            $this->request->data['VwImage']['image_thumb'] = $image_thumb;
            $this->request->data['VwImage']['thumb_height'] = $thumb_height;
            $this->request->data['VwImage']['thumb_width'] = $thumb_width;
            if ($this->VwImage->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('This image has been save');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('This Image could not be saved. Please try again.');
            }
        } else {

            $this->Session->setFlash('Unsupported Image Type could not be saved. Please try again.');
        }           
    }
    if (empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->request->data = $this->VwImage->read(null, $id);
    /** pr($this->request->data); die; **/
    }
}
```

Cheers
Mike

Comment: Could you add your Controller code for the edit action in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem:**

According to the [CakePHP 2.0 book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html):

> Due to the limitations of HTML itself, it is not possible to put
>   default values into input fields of type ‘file’. Each time the form is
>   displayed, the value inside will be empty.

While I'm sure there are ways you could hack it (with javascript), it's non-standard practice to try to set a default into that field.  When you select a file via a "file" input, it's inserting a path to a local file.  How would you know what path that is?

---

**The Solution:**

Instead, add a line above or below that shows "previous filename" with it's filename, or if it's an image, show a thumbnail of previous file.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Kinda what I suspected